# Problem with Computercraft: '=' expected near 'monitor'

Tags: lua, computercraft

I am new to computercraft and have a problem with my code.

[image: 1]

The error is

> '=' expected near 'monitor'

Do anyone know the problem and can fix it?

Comment: Try `monitor.clear()`

Comment: Perhaps one of these dots after `monitor` is not really a dot.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff, that does not explain the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Adding the parentheses worked.

Comment: @PotatoOrSomethin Lua knows two types of statements: Assignments and function calls. Your last line was an expression, but not a statement. The "`=` expected" tells you that it expected a statement (assignment statement). Adding the parentheses made it a call statement and thus made your program syntactically valid again.

Comment: You should write this as an answer so that @PotatoOrSomethin can accept...

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)